# question from the idea of relative acceleration

Tags: kinematics, relative-motion

the accelerations of a particle as seen from two frames $S_1$ and $S_2$ have equal magnitude $4 m/s^2$
so my teacher said that the acceleration of $S_2$ with respect to $S_1$ may be anything between zero and $8 m/s^2$
can u please show me this mathematically ?

Comment: Can you give us some more information about the dimensionality of the problem. I can guess from the range of possibility for the relative acceleration between the two systems that is at least two dimensional, however since you're confused I'm concerned that the teacher may have presented the problem as happening along a line.

Comment: Ask your teacher to show you.  Hint: triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two accelerations are $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ then the relative acceleration of motion $A$ relative to motion $B$ is $\vec a - \vec b$.

It is just a vector addition of two acceleration which in terms of diagrams is shown below.

[image]

The left had diagram is for the two accelerations being in opposite directions and the right hand diagram is for the two accelerations being the the same direction.

Comment: thnk u very much :) that answers my ques